# Laravel Passport Password Grant Refresh Token

Tags: php, ios, laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

Trying to wrap my head around using Laravel's Passport with mobile clients. The Password Grant type of authentication seems to be the way to go, and i have it working with my iOS app, however i can't get token refreshing to work.

When authenticating i get a `token` and a `refresh token` which i store, however when the token expires, calling the `oauth/token/refresh` route doesn't work. The route is using the `web` middleware which means my app using the api route can't access it. I'm not sure if they intended for mobile clients to never refresh or if they wanted you to roll your own refreshing? If anyone has insight on how this is supposed to work, that'd be great.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `oauth/token/refresh` route is not for refreshing access tokens. It is used to refresh transient tokens, which are used when you consume your own API from your javascript.

To use your `refresh_token` to refresh your access token, you need to call the `oauth/token` route with the `grant_type` of `refresh_token`.

This is the example provided by [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#refreshing-tokens):

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token' => 'the-refresh-token',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

One note about scopes, when you refresh the token, you can only obtain identical or narrower scopes than the original access token. If you attempt to get a scope that was not provided by the original access token, you will get an error.

Comment: Wow, i don't know how that was escaping me, i guess i just assumed i would be calling a completely different route to refresh the token. Thanks!

Comment: Hey did you ever get this to work? I have the same issue and I have the settings exactly like how it is above. I've tried everything and its driving me crazy, this is the error message i get. League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException: The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.

Comment: If you could help me out with how you solved it that would be awesome. also are you storing the refresh token in a cookie or passing it straight from the browser? which is not recommended..

Comment: Ufff, this is not in Laravel passport documentation, I think I checked it and I didn't find it, thank you !!

Answer (score 5):

I've done something like.

1. Created an endpoint for grant refresh token.

and in my controller,

```
public function userRefreshToken(Request $request)
{
    $client = DB::table('oauth_clients')
        ->where('password_client', true)
        ->first();

    $data = [
        'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token' => $request->refresh_token,
        'client_id' => $client->id,
        'client_secret' => $client->secret,
        'scope' => ''
    ];
    $request = Request::create('/oauth/token', 'POST', $data);
    $content = json_decode(app()->handle($request)->getContent());

    return response()->json([
        'error' => false,
        'data' => [
            'meta' => [
                'token' => $content->access_token,
                'refresh_token' => $content->refresh_token,
                'type' => 'Bearer'
            ]
        ]
    ], Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```