# How to add custom claims to laravel-passport Access token?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

i just used laravel-passport,it is same as jwt auth.

i want to add some custom claims to my accessToken, is it possible ??

> i want to pass `2fa_status => true` in access token and while API call
>   with this access token i also want that claim from token.

**For e.g**  (**Expected Claims Of Token**)

```
{
  "aud": "7",
  "jti": "123",
  "iat": 1568368682,
  "nbf": 1568368682,
  "exp": 1599991082,
  "sub": "2",
  "scopes": [],
  "2fa_status": false
}
```

I'm generating token as below:

```
  $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why need the custom claims?

Comment: e.g in token i want to pass that it is token of member or user. i have two separate guards. Thanks

Comment: i have updated my question please check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Think something you can do is very similar to an answer of the this question: 
[Customising token response Laravel Passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146964/customising-token-response-laravel-passport)

While in your own BearerTokenResponse class, override generateHttpResponse method, inside it you can add whatever to the access token before convert it to JWT:

```
    public function generateHttpResponse(ResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $expireDateTime = $this->accessToken->getExpiryDateTime()->getTimestamp();

        // add custom claims here, ie. $this->accessToken->withClaim('name', 'value');

        $jwtAccessToken = $this->accessToken->convertToJWT($this->privateKey);

        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation but I used password grant client to issue token to user during authentication and I need to used the personal access token for user to generate an access token for their self to be used in their 3rd party applications. You can do a workaround by updating the scope.I also need to verify the user if the 2fa has been pass.

in your

```php
AuthServiceProvider.php

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::routes(function ($router) {
            $router->forAccessTokens();
            $router->forPersonalAccessTokens();
            $router->forTransientTokens(); // register the transient token. skip if all routes are enabled
        });

        // Add scope to verify the user
        // take note that here 2 scope for this due to refresh token scope
        Passport::tokensCan([
            '2fa-pass' => '2FA Pass',
            '2fa-not-pass' => '2FA Pass',
        ]);
    }
```

next step is in your Authentication process where you send the password grant type

```php
  // I'm using route::dispatch to do a proxy request
  // you can use Guzzle if you want
  $request->request->add([
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'client_id' => 'client-id',
     client_secret' => 'client-secret',
    'username' => $credentials['email'],
    'password' => $credentials['password'],
    'scope' => '2fa-not-pass 2fa-pass' // take note that I added the two scope here
  ]);

  $tokenRequest = Request::create('/oauth/token', 'POST');

  $response = \Route::dispatch($tokenRequest);
```

then in your 2FA Verification process

```php
   // your process of verifying the 2FA code

   // after that you need to update the scope by doing a refresh token
   $request->request->add([
     'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
     'refresh_token' => $request->input('refresh_token'),
     'client_id' => 'client-id',
     'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
     'scope' => '2fa-pass' // I removed the 2fa-not-pass in refreshing the token
    ]);

  $tokenRequest = Request::create('/oauth/token', 'POST');

  $response = \Route::dispatch($tokenRequest);
```

Take note about the scopes, when you refresh the token, you can only obtain identical or narrower scopes than the original access token. If you attempt to get a scope that was not provided by the original access token, you will get an error.
- patricus

answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45856634/11537130

take note that this will be generate a new token with new scope

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for the answer, this worked for me for Laravel 9 and Passport 11.

You need to create `CustomClaimsAccessTokenTrait.php` and add your custom claims in it:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Services\Tokens;

use App\Models\User;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Token;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Entities\Traits\AccessTokenTrait;

trait CustomClaimsAccessTokenTrait
{
    use AccessTokenTrait;

    /**
     * Generate a JWT from the access token
     *
     * @return Token
     */
    private function convertToJWT()
    {
        $this->initJwtConfiguration();

        return $this->jwtConfiguration->builder()
            ->permittedFor($this->getClient()->getIdentifier())
            ->identifiedBy($this->getIdentifier())
            ->issuedAt(new \DateTimeImmutable())
            ->canOnlyBeUsedAfter(new \DateTimeImmutable())
            ->expiresAt($this->getExpiryDateTime())
            ->relatedTo((string)$this->getUserIdentifier())
            ->withClaim('scopes', $this->getScopes())
            ->withClaim('custom', 'myCustomClaim') // your custom claim
            ->getToken($this->jwtConfiguration->signer(), $this->jwtConfiguration->signingKey());
    }

    /**
     * Generate a string representation from the access token
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->convertToJWT()->toString();
    }
}
```

Then you have to create `CustomTokenAccess.php` that uses our `CustomClaimsAccessTokenTrait`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Services\Tokens;

use Laravel\Passport\Bridge\AccessToken;

class CustomAccessToken extends AccessToken
{
    use CustomClaimsAccessTokenTrait;
}
```

Now what you have to do is to tell Passport to use our `CustomAccessToken` class as `AccessToken` entity, so in `AuthServiceProvider.php` in `boot` method add:

```php
public function boot()
{
    // ...
    Passport::useAccessTokenEntity(CustomAccessToken::class);
}
```

Now when you debug JWT Token there's the result:

```json
{
  "aud": "7",
  "jti": "...",
  "iat": 1701432944.525137,
  "nbf": 1701432944.52514,
  "exp": 1701433244.452095,
  "sub": "139400",
  "scopes": [
    "patient-app"
  ],
  "custom": "myCustomClaim"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it is possible

add this to `AuthServiceProvider`

```
Passport::routes();
Passport::personalAccessClientId(1); //<-- this 1 is id of your personal key
Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(15));
Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30));
```

now your can create new token like this

```
$user->createToken('email')->accessToken; // you can change email to any for remember why this code generated like social facebook
```

according to [documents](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#managing-personal-access-tokens) for add more params try this

```
$user->createToken('email', ['extra' => 'params'])->accessToken;
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but I don;t want to create new token i already have a token generated, i want to add some custom proprieties into it.

Comment: @VishalRibdiya check i added `$user->createToken('email', ['extra' => 'params'])->accessToken;` on my answer

Comment: i think there is some communication gap, i have updated my question please check it again and let me know if you can help. 

Thanks

Comment: `$user->createToken('email', ['extra' => 'params'])` this will not work because second param is SCOPES not extra param.

Comment: IT WILL RETURN ERROR `The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed`

Comment: i think you are doing wrong this handle by backend like laravel check if `2fa_status` false than `return response()->json(['token' => $userToken, '2fa_status' => $2fa_status]);`

Comment: it is just an example, i need to pass claim with `[key => value]`, as we doing into JWT.